# what is the extension of an executable file in an xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, appledoc

I downloaded apple researchkit last month and run its sample. It worked and every thing was fine. This week i tried to run it , i had build failed and the error is that i need to have appledoc:

error: appledoc is required for building ResearchKit's documentation. See http://appledoc.gentlebytes.com

I did some research and i found this page

```
 [1]: https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc#quick-install
```

I downloaded the project and built it and i found my

> build directory.

**But**, i didn't know what is the executable file in this directory and how can i add it to the path. Can someone help me ? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message when I opened a working ResearchKit project that was stored in Dropbox on a different computer from the one it was created on. I noticed that there was a file called "doc" in the Target section of the ResearchKit.xcodeproj. Deleting that file resolved the problem. I have no idea how the "doc" file got there in the first place, but I've duplicated the problem (and solution) since.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete appledocs you may end up having problems launching the simulator or just have another dependency problem resurface later. Instead resolve the issue of the location of your ResearchKit Folder and ResearchKit.xcodeproj file.

Remove the existing reference to ResearchKit.xcodeproj

- Click on ResearchKit.
- Right Click
- Select Delete
- Select Remove Reference [DO NOT DELETE]

In your Downloads/Documents/other folder you should have a folder named ResearchKit that contains multiple folders and files, including a second ResearchKit folder, a readme file and the ResearchKit.xcodeproj. As instructed in the readme file:

- Transfer/copy the main ResearchKit folder into your App folder (in Documents/Downloads/etc)
- Drag and drop ResearchKit.xcodeproj from the ResearchKit folder into the navigation pane of your app in Xcode, under your main project.

Embed ReserachKit.framework into your App as follows:

- Add ResearchKit under Target > General > Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content